# How to display a string, based on number in a form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the user entering a post-number in a form-field, and then I want to display the town with that post-number.

I have the server-side function set up, it takes a variable from the URL and returns a plain string.

As I see it, I need to get the variable from the form-field after the user has written it and the focus has left the form-field, use that number in an `XMLHttpRequest` call to the server and display the resulted string.

But the problem is, that I've never written any JavaScript, more complex than a Hello World. So I would like some help with writing the JavaScript for that page, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to JavaScript I won't recommend using any JS framework for this.

To get the value from an input box you can use

```
document.getElementById("txt1").value;
```

where `txt1` is the `id` of the input element.

Then you can append the element value to the query string and call the server-side function. And if the response text is a plain string put that inside a `div` or `span`

```
document.getElementById("divTown").innerText = "response string"; // for IE

document.getElementById("divTown").textContent = "response string"; // for FF
```

You can get a basic understanding of AJAX and JavaScript read these

**[AJAX Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp)**

**[JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)**

Comment: w3schools.com? You must be joking :)

Comment: I think for a beginner it is a nice site.

Comment: **There's nothing nice about w3schools.com**. I don't see a reason for beginners to start with bad practices. I mean, seriously... look at this wonderful "form validation" script - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp. Instead of providing clear and simple solution (which is trivial), w3schools decides to introduce completely unnecessary `with` together with an ancient, non-standard form elements access (`formEl.foo` instead of `formEl.elements.foo`). As if that wasn't enough, an example is based on invalid and poor HTML (inputs have no labels, doctype is missing, no title).